# ASP Button does nothing OnClick when div with UpdatePanel is present

Tags: asp.net

I am having trouble to solve this problem. The buttons were working but now they do nothing when clicked.

This is the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnEnviar" Text="Send" runat="server" OnClick="RegisterUser" />
```

In code behind:

```
   protected void RegisterUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    ...
   }
```

..But when clicked, the `RegisterUser()` isn't being called (breakpoint tested).

I already tried to create another button, double click it and then paste the code to it, and also does nothing.

I've tried adding to `PageLoad`:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnEnviar.Click += new EventHandler(RegisterUser);
    }
```

Also with no effect.

**EDIT**: (see EDIT 2) This is the whole page (sorry about the code, was just a quick design so i could work on SQL layer for this, the button was working fine when i did some time ago, now i came back to change the design and realized it stopped working).

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MP.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="registar.aspx.cs" Inherits="operacao.registar" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<div style="margin: auto">
    <table style="border: 0px; width: 60%">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3" style="background-color: #3A5896;color:white;">Operação</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtRegistarFName" runat="server" placeholder="Primeiro nome" CssClass="txtbox"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtRegistarLName" runat="server" placeholder="Último nome (opcional)" CssClass="txtbox"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="obrigatório" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtRegistarFName"
                    runat="server" Display="Dynamic" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtRegistarPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" placeholder="Nova password" CssClass="txtbox" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"/></td>
            <td>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="obrigatório" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtRegistarPassword"
                    runat="server" Display="Dynamic" />
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtRegistarConfirmPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" placeholder="Repetir password" CssClass="txtbox" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" /></td>
            <td>
                <asp:CompareValidator ErrorMessage="passwords diferentes" ForeColor="Red" ControlToCompare="txtRegistarPassword"
                    ControlToValidate="txtRegistarConfirmPassword" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtRegistarEmail" runat="server" placeholder="e-m@il" CssClass="txtbox" /></td>
            <td>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="obrigatório" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"
                    ControlToValidate="txtRegistarEmail" runat="server" />
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
                    ControlToValidate="txtregistarEmail" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="e-mail inválido" />
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnEnviar" Text="Enviar" runat="server" OnClick="RegisterUser" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnNovoRegisto" runat="server" Text="Registar" OnClick="btnNovoRegisto_Click" />
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**EDIT 2**: I was able to identify what is causing this. I created a Chat meanwhile with UpdatePanel on it. I have a divChatContainer where i add programatically the content (more divs with chat text and a textbox and button at the end) and then to an UpdatePanel, which is added to the following container, located in the MasterPage file. As soon as i remove this div, the buttons work again. The button inside the UpdatePanel always work.

```
<div id="divChatContainer" runat="server" style="overflow-y: scroll; word-wrap: break-word; width: 19%; max-height: 35%; position: fixed; right: 0px; bottom: 0%;">CHAT</div><br />
```

Comment: Make sure the buttons are within a form

Comment: Yes, they are in a page inside a ContentPlaceHolder (MasterPage)

Comment: Please post your entire page. Mistypes in any asp.net tag could be causing this sort of problems, like pointing a page to the wrong code behind class (typical when copying and pasting files), or a missing form tag, a missing runat="server", etc.

Comment: I've edited the post and pasted the whole page.

Comment: Where is your form tag, check in master page?, its needed to post back to server

Comment: I recreated your page (without Master) and ran it on a Visual Studio 2010 project. It ran just fine.

Comment: See the EDIT 2 on my post, please.

Comment: That div is not closed with a "</div>". Just a mistype or could that be part of the problem? Also remember that buttons inside an UpdatePanel won't fire unless you properly set it up (ChildrenAsTriggers="true", if I recall correctly).

Comment: It's closed, i just didn't paste because there was many comments inside it. I'll close the div here in SO not to cause confusion.

Comment: Check the HTML that is being sent to the browser. Every ASP.NET control is translated to it's HTML counterpart. For instance, asp:Button is an <input> tag. Maybe seeing the HTML and Javascript as the browser sees it will highlight the problem. Or paste it here and we'll check it out, too.

Comment: I've posted another question so this don't get messy. Feel free to check it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The buttons in asp.net triggers by JavaScript. Just check your browser settings and make sure the JavaScript is enabled.
If previously it was working it might be the case.